# Conditional formatting in Google sheets to indicate overages

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

To help identify issues faster I am trying to add conditional formatting for column Z to turn red if the amount in that column is greater than the amount in the columns AA or AB and only if column AA or AB is not 0.

I tried the following after putting “Z2:Z” for the **Apply to range** and “Custom formula is” for the **Format rules**:

> =OR(Z2>AA2, Z2>AB2)

*Also, I am starting from row 2 as row 1 contains the headers.*

But I can not figure out how to specify the not 0 part for both column AA and AB.

This feels like it should be a pretty basic formula but I am bit rusty on my functions/statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=OR(AND(Z2>AA2,AA2<>0), AND(Z2>AB2,AB2<>0))
```

Comment: Pretty close, I reckon, but the OP says "and only if column AA or AB is not 0." So as I read it... for example, it's not just if (Z>AA and AA<>0), but it's if AB<>0.

Comment: A suggestion: `=OR(AND(Z2>AA2,AA2<>0,AB2<>0), AND(Z2>AB2,AB2<>0,AA2<>0))`

Comment: Thank you both, this worked out perfectly.